# How to add preview functionality for markdown/LaTex code in ReactJS application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Recently I have create a fullstack bloging website [here](https://passion4learning.herokuapp.com/). For writing blog I used [react-quill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) because its extensible architecture and an expressive API, I can completely customize it to fulfill my needs. But Now I feeling that I need something which can handle [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) also. I was wondering is there **any library which can handle both or at least LaTeX one with an expressive API**?

And one more question, **How stackoverflow give preview system(live preview of our markdown/LaTex code) when we ask a question**? Because it's a really an important functionality when you writing a blog. It will be great help if anyone let me informed anything related with this.

---

I found [react-latex](https://github.com/zzish/react-latex#react-latex-) and [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown#react-markdown) to handle markdown and LaTex seperately. But still hanging on how to setup preview functionality. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Input the text to `react-markdown` and preview the output in a div element.

You can check the source code of some open-source online markdown editor. They support latex also.

Reference:

- [stackedit](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit)